# Examples of WCF CRUD operations for Oracle?

Tags: wcf, oracle

I'm working on exposing access to an Oracle database table for a SharePoint implementation.

From what I've seen, Oracle is not directly supported by BDC, so I'm trying to write a WCF service to perform the CRUD operations against my table.

I've been researching on Google with very limited success. Can anybody point me to an example of using WCF to modify data in an Oracle database?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to figure this out by following this tutorial (leaving out the Silverlight stuff since I didn't need Silverlight)

[How to connect to Oracle database using WCF in Silverlight](http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/uploadfile/anavijai/how-to-connect-to-oracle-database-using-wcf-in-silverlight/)